# Getting assembly error while building Azure function app

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, visual-studio-2019

While building a .net Azure function app from Azure devops I am getting these warnings can anyone guide me on this if it impacts the functionality or we can ignore

2021-12-29T13:25:34.28599212

2021-12-29T13:25:40.72761782 Determining projects to restore... 2021-12-29T13:26:25.38403842 ##[warning]AzureResources\FunctionApp\FunctionApp.csproj(0,0): Warning MU1781: Package

'Microsoft.Crm5dk.CoreAssemblies 9.0.2.42' was restored using .NET Framework, Version=v4.6.1, .NET Framework, Version v4.6.2, NETFramework, Version=v4.7, NETFramework, Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework, Version=v4.7.2, NETFramework, Version=v4.8 instead of the project target framework .NETCoreApp,Version 3.1. This package may

not be fully compatible with your project. 2021-12-29T13:26:25.38575492 D:\a\1\s\AzureResources\FunctionApp\FunctionApp.csproj: warning NU1701: Package

*Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies 9.0.2.42' was restored using.NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1, NETFramework, Version=v4.6.2, NETFramework, Version=v4.7,

not be fully compatible with your project.

2021-12-29T13:26:25.38631672 ##[warning]AzureResources\FunctionApp\FunctionApp.csproj(0,0): Warning NU1781: Package

NETFramework, Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework, Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework, Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework.NETCoreApp,Version 3.1. This package may

Microsoft. CrmSdk.XrmTooling. CoreAssembly 9.1.0.92' was restored using .NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework, Version=4.7, .NETFramework, Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework, Version=v4.7.2, .NET Framework, Version=v4.8 instead of the project target framework NETCoreApp, Version v3.1. This package may 2021-12-29T13:26:25.38659362 D:\a\1\s\AzureResource\FunctionApp\FunctionApp.csproj: warning NU1791: Package

not be fully compatible with your project.

Microsoft. CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly 9.1.0.92' was restored using .NETFramework, Versionsv4.6.1, .NETFramework, Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework, Version4.7,

.NET Framework, Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework, Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework, Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework .NETCoreApp, Version v3.1'. This package may

not be fully compatible with your project.

2021-12-29T13:26:25.8573565Z Restored D:\a\1\s\AzureResources\FunctionApp\FunctionApp.csproj (in 43.24 sec).

2021-12-29T13:26:26.35778372 ##[warning]AzureResources\FunctionApp\FunctionApp.csproj(0,0): Warning M1791: Package 'Microsoft.Crm5dk.CoreAssemblies 9.0.2.42' was restored using.NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1, .NET Framework, Version=v4.6.2, NETFramework, Version=v4.7,

.NET Framework, Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework, Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework, Version=v4.8° instead of the project target framework.NETCoreApp, Versionev3.1. This package may

not be fully compatible with your project.

2021-12-29T13:26:26.35869792 D:\a\1\s\AzureResources\FunctionApp\FunctionApp.csproj warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Crmsdk.CoreAssemblies 9.0.2.42' was restored using .NET Framework, Version=v4.6.1, .NET Framework, Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework, Version 4.7, .NETFramework, Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework, Version=v4.7.2, .NET Framework, Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework.NETCoreApp, Version v3.1. This package may

not be fully compatible with your project.

2021-12-29T13:26:26.3596329Z ##[warning]AzureResources\FunctionApp\FunctionApp.csproj(0,0): Warning NU1791: Package 'Microsoft.CrmSdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly 9.1.8.92' was restored using .NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework, Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework, rsion=v4.7 .NET Framework, Version=v4.7.1, .NET Framework, Version=v4.7.2, .NET Framework, Version=v4.8 instead of the project target framework .NETCoreApp, Version=v3.1. This package may

not be fully compatible with your project.

2821-12-29T13:26:26.3601884Z D:\a\1\s\AzureResource\FunctionApp\FunctionApp.csproj: warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Crmsdk.XrmTooling.CoreAssembly 9.1.0.92' was restored using.NETFramework, Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework, Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework, Version v4.7,

.NETFramework, Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework, Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework, Version=v4.8 instead of the project target framework.NETCoreApp, Version v3.1. This package may

not be fully compatible with your project.

2021-12-29T13:26:34.93408682
FunctionApp -> D: \a\1\s\AzureResources\FunctionApp\publish_output\bin\FunctionApp.dll

Comment: These are *warnings*.  Q: Is anything actually "broken"?  Is any functionality impaired?  See also this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60766003/421195

Answer (score 0):

You were using the incompatible versions of .NetFramework packages , please try to update those packages, it will resolve the warnings .

Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies package requires .NET Framework 4.6.2 and above after releasing v9.0.2.9, please check release notes from official NuGet page [www.nuget.org/.../Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies/)

So, you have to upgrade your project .NET Framework version